# The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. How to solve?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Entity component

```cs
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public EntityScriptableObject ScriptableObject
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        Transform interactionPoint;

        switch (ScriptableObject.Type)
        {
            case EntityType.Key:
                Player.Inventory.Add(this as Item);
                Destroy(gameObject);

                break;
            case EntityType.VideoTape:
                Player.Inventory.Add(this as Item);
                Destroy(gameObject);

                break;
            case EntityType.Note:
                Player.Journal.Add(this as Document);

                Destroy(gameObject);

                break;
            case EntityType.Painting:
                GameManager.ChangeTypeOfControll(TypesOfControl.InspectionControll);
                ObjectInspectorController.Instance.enabled = true;
                ObjectInspectorController.Instance.Initialize(this);

                break;
            case EntityType.TV:
                GameManager.PauseGame();

                interactionPoint = InteractionPoints.Instance.TV.transform;
                InteractionController.Instance.InteractionPoint = interactionPoint;
                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.TV;
                InteractionController.Instance.MoveToInteractionPoint();

                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction += StopInteraction;

                UIController.Instance.OpenInventory();
                PlayerController.Instance.enabled = false;

                break;
            case EntityType.Door:
                DoorController door = gameObject.GetComponent<DoorController>();

                if (door.IsOpen)
                    door.CloseDoor();
                else
                    door.OpenDoor();

                break;
            case EntityType.SafeDigital:
                GameManager.PauseGame();
                GameManager.ChangeTypeOfControll(TypesOfControl.InteractionControl);

                interactionPoint = InteractionPoints.Instance.SafeDigital.transform;
                InteractionController.Instance.InteractionPoint = interactionPoint;
                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.SafeNumeric;
                InteractionController.Instance.MoveToInteractionPoint();

                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction += StopInteraction;

                PlayerController.Instance.enabled = false;
                CameraController.Instance.enabled = false;

                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.visible = true;

                gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<SafeDoor>().enabled = true;

                break;
            case EntityType.SafePadlock:
                GameManager.PauseGame();
                GameManager.ChangeTypeOfControll(TypesOfControl.InteractionControl);

                interactionPoint = InteractionPoints.Instance.SafePadlock.transform;
                InteractionController.Instance.InteractionPoint = interactionPoint;
                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.SafePadlock;
                InteractionController.Instance.MoveToInteractionPoint();

                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction += StopInteraction;

                PlayerController.Instance.enabled = false;
                CameraController.Instance.enabled = false;

                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.visible = true;

                gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Padlock>().enabled = true;

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    public void StopInteraction()
    {
        switch (ScriptableObject.Type)
        {
            case EntityType.Key:
                break;
            case EntityType.VideoTape:
                break;
            case EntityType.Note:
                break;
            case EntityType.Painting:
                break;
            case EntityType.TV:
                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction -= StopInteraction;

                InteractionController.Instance.ReturnToInteractionPosition();
                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.None;

                GameManager.ResumeGame();

                break;
            case EntityType.Door:
                break;
            case EntityType.SafeDigital:
                gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<SafeDoor>().enabled = false;

                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                Cursor.visible = false;

                PlayerController.Instance.enabled = true;
                CameraController.Instance.enabled = true;

                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction -= StopInteraction;

                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.None;
                InteractionController.Instance.ReturnToInteractionPosition();

                GameManager.ChangeTypeOfControll(TypesOfControl.PlayerControl);
                GameManager.ResumeGame();

                break;
            case EntityType.SafePadlock:
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                Cursor.visible = false;

                PlayerController.Instance.enabled = true;
                CameraController.Instance.enabled = true;

                InteractionController.Instance.OnStopInteraction -= StopInteraction;

                InteractionController.Instance.CurrentInteraction = InteractionType.None;
                InteractionController.Instance.ReturnToInteractionPosition();

                GameManager.ChangeTypeOfControll(TypesOfControl.PlayerControl);
                GameManager.ResumeGame();

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Document class which is inherited from it

```cs
public class Document : Entity
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public new DocumentScriptableObject ScriptableObject
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        switch (ScriptableObject.Type)
        {
            case EntityType.Key:
                break;
            case EntityType.VideoTape:
                break;
            case EntityType.Note:
                DocumentInspectorController.Instance.enabled = true;
                DocumentInspectorController.Instance.Initialize(ScriptableObject.Text);

                break;
            case EntityType.Painting:
                break;
            case EntityType.TV:
                break;
            case EntityType.Door:
                break;
            case EntityType.SafeDigital:
                break;
            case EntityType.SafePadlock:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

There are no problems with Entity, but when adding a Document component to a Unity object it gives the following error:
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. This is not supported: Base(MonoBehaviour) _scriptableObject.

[image: img]

Also there is another issue. _scriptableObject field is duplicated in the inspector.

[image: img2]

As I understand it, the problem appears because I am trying to serialize fields with the same name in the base and inherited classes. The question is whether it is possible (and whether it is necessary) to fix this error, because the code, apparently, compiles and works as I intended. Also, what worries me more is that the fields are duplicated in the inspector, although when I try to pass a reference to an object there, it is passed to both fields at once. Is this a unity bug or is it because I'm not hiding field of the base class? If this is the case, then why types of field are the same in the inspector, yet they are different in the base and inherited classes? Could this cause problems in the future if I leave it like this?

I tried changing the names, then another problem appears.

[image: img3]

Now, due to the fact that the base class field is also serialized, both fields from the base class and from the inherited class appear in the inspector. My code does not assume that in the Document component I can use a reference of the type other than DocumentScriptableObject. And if I simply leave the field empty, NullReferenceExceptions will be thrown when interacting with the object.Same problem appears if try to use only serialized properties without fields using [field: SerializeField]. I tried to hide the field of the base class by making it protected, and in the inherited class I marked it as new. But then the first problem with serialization error returns.

Is there any way to achieve serialization of field/property in an inherited class without base class fields/properties appearing in the inspector?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]

Comment: `Also there is another issue. _scriptableObject field is duplicated in the inspector.` .. well that **IS** the issue the warning is referring to ;) You have the same field `_scriptableObject` implemented once in `Entity` and once in `Document` which inherits from (in other words **IS**) an `Entity` itself => it has both fields - it just doesn't se it because the base one is **private** ... is there a reason why you inherit there at all if you basically re-declare / overwrite both members anyway ....?

Comment: @derHugo I added functionality to classes so it would be clearer why I need inheritance. Also Im using [field: SerializeField] instead of regular private fields. That resolved serialization error but now in th inspector both properties from base and inherited class appears.

Comment: this doesn't show at all why you need inheritance tbh .. it even makes clearer that you probably don't ...

Comment: @derHugo hmm, but why? I need to be able to read only documents but not other entities. I also added a second class that derives from Entity called Item and it has method Use() so now items can be used but not read. And you can interact with items, documents and entities. How can I achieve the same implementation without inheritance or copying? I thought that was the point of inheritance.

Comment: well if they all require different fields - what about one main class below `Entity` like e.g. `BaseInteractable` and then everything inherits from that one instead but `Entity` is not in the same inheritance branch as `Document` since these have different fields and different additional methods ...

Answer (score 0):

Unity use reflection to serialize things that mark with `[SerializeField]` attribute in your class. If you defined 2 field with same name in both base and derived class, unity will try to serialize both of them into .meta file, so the last serialized things will appear twice in your inspector, which is `DocumentScriptableObjet`.

The second things is not a problem, since you can directly remove `[SerializeField]` declared in base class.